# How to add button effects in swift SKSpriteNode

Tags: swift, button, skspritenode

I have a Var Button.

```
var soundButton: SKSpriteNode! = nil
```

and the details is rest like.

```
soundButton           =   SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "\(soundImg)")
soundButton.position  =   CGPoint(x: frame.size.width*0.08 , y:frame.size.width*0.08);
soundButton.size      =   CGSizeMake(frame.size.width*0.10,frame.size.width*0.10 )
self.addChild(soundButton)
```

Than how can I add button effects like Button Color light when I click on it and make a sound also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is you can change the image when button is selected.

like this way into your `touchesBegan` method:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for touch in (touches as! Set<UITouch>) {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if self.nodeAtPoint(location) == self. soundButton {
            soundButton.texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "soundSelected")

        }
    }
}
```

If you want to go to another scene with delay and you want transition you can use this code into your `if` statement:

```
let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
let letsPlay = playScene(size: self.size)
self.view?.presentScene(letsPlay, transition: reveal)
```

Comment: One more thing when i click button the view change to another Screen. Then how can i use time delay. So it show properly. Right now it change the view Quickly. Is there any way to Go no another screen after show the change image on button.

Comment: if nextButton.containsPoint(location) {
                nextButton     =   SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "button2")
                let reveal = SKTransition.flipHorizontalWithDuration(0.5)
                let shopScene = ShopScene(size: self.size, controller: self.vc)
                self.view?.presentScene(shopScene, transition: reveal)
            }